# How to check TempData value in my view after a form post?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, if-statement, view, tempdata

I fill my TempData from a `FormCollection` and then I try to check the value of my `TempData` in my view with MVC 4 but my `if` statement isn't working as I expect. Here is my code.

**Controller :**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestForm(FormCollection data) 
{
    TempData["username"] = data["var"].ToString(); //data["var"] == "abcd"
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**View:**

```
@if (TempData["var"] == "abcd") 
{
    <span>Check</span> //Never displayed
}
else
{
    @TempData["var"]; // Display "abcd"
}
```

This looks like really simple and I don't understand why I can't display this `Check`. Can you help me ?

Comment: know **how to use** `TempData` properly  check [this](http://sampathloku.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-use-aspnet-mvc-tempdata-properly.html)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please try this

```
var tempval = TempData["var"];
```

then write your if statement as follow

```
@if (tempval.ToString() == "abcd") 
{
    <span>Check</span> //Never displayed
}
else
{
    <span>@tempval</span>; // Display "abcd"
}
```

Comment: I tried and I have the same result.  `@tempval` gives me the good value but `if(@tempval == "myvalue") ` doesn't return true.

Answer (score 6):

Try change `TempData.Add("var", "abcd");`

to

```
TempData['var'] = "abcd";
```

Update:

In My controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TempData["var"] = "abcd";
        return View();
    }
```

In my view:

```
// I cast to string to make sure it's checking for the correct TempData (string)
@if ((string)TempData["var"] == "abcd")
{
   <span>Check</span>
}
else
{
   @TempData["var"].ToString()
}
```

Comment: See my updated answer on how simply this should really work. If this not helps you, I would need some more info/code to help you out.

Comment: Thanks Lars. It was a problems troubling me for some time now how I couldn't do a conditional on a TempData value. Turns out it's an object! I am free at last!

Answer (score 0):

Before starting any block of code in MVC View always start using @{ } then write any line of code and terminate with semicolon(;)

[image]