# Strongly-typed Session in ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I'm trying to create a strongly-typed session object. Let's assume I want to store the user's name and email in the session. My base controller would take care of that, so I can always assume that the values are present in the session.

Currently, I can refer to them in my Razor view like this:

```
Email: @Session["Email"]<br/>
Name: @Session["Name"]<br/>
```

What I would like is to do something like this:

```
Email: @Session.Email<br/>
Name: @Session.Name<br/>
```

I think that the way to do this would be to extend the **HttpContext.Session** object. Something similar to:

```
class MySession : HttpSessionState {

    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

I tried creating my own session provider, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178589.aspx), but this does not get exposed in the HttpContext, Controller or View.

There is a good workaround using extension methods as described [here](http://coding.grax.com/2013/06/simple-strongly-typed-pattern-for.html). This results in a slightly different syntax and it's not exactly what I wanted:

```
Email: @Session.Email()<br/>
Name: @Session.Name()<br/>
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use TempData for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use *TempData*. I advice for you look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-2cplusViewBagplusandplusTem),[this](http://sampathloku.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-use-aspnet-mvc-tempdata-properly.html) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857490/how-to-check-tempdata-value-in-my-view-after-a-form-post/17857645#17857645)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not sure it's what I want. I wanted to persist something in the session so that it's accessible from anywhere in the application and lasts throughout the whole session lifecycle. TempData does not seem to do this.